# issue to set the html input date type value with the sqldatareader value

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using the html input tag for my form

```
<input id="signdate" type="date" class="textarea" runat="server" readonly/>
```

The form will be populated with data using sqldatareader

```
signdate.Value = String.Format("{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", reader["RequestedDate"]);
```

The column is in datetime so I convert to date only using String.Format . But when the form is load, the input field only show 'mm/dd/yyyy' instead of the actual datetime stored in the database.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Update: Issue resolved. It turns out I have to format the string to "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" which will show up in the front end.

Comment: you formatted to `mm/dd/yyyy` and don't want to display in `mm/dd/yyyy` in the form?

Comment: @techspider,  I mean the text shows 'mm/dd/yyyy' not in ''mm/dd/yyyy' format. I should show actual value.

Comment: check these two... change to `Convert.ToDateTime(reader["......"].ToString())` and format to `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Change the format to MM/dd/yyyy then place a break point on `signdate.Value` - does it have the right value?

Comment: @DenisWessels, hi Denis, yes. It does have the correct value when I debug, but at the front end, it is still just 'mm/dd/yyyy'